# Why the left side size in for each is not equal to the right side?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

The declared size in `for-each` is always less than the size of the array.why ?

```
int[][][] c = {{{1,2,3}}};
for(int [][] z : c )
    //code
```

c is a 3D array so should z, right?
like:

```
int[][][] c = {{{1,2,3}}};
for (int[][][] z : c) // which is syntactically wrong
    //code
```

Thank you in advance.

The answer as I understand it from the comments and the below answer:  the declaration inside `for-each`

in the 3D array `for-each` considers every 2D array as an element,

in the 2D array `for-each` considers every 1D array as an element and so on..

in the 1D array it takes the elements of the array directly as elements.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The variable in the `for` loop is whatever the array contains. In your first example, the array contains integers. In the second example, the array contains integer arrays (well, in this case only one element but that's unimportant in how the loop is written).

Comment: Maybe you could put some print statements inside the loop so we could understand what you are seeing?

Comment: Because the for-each loop is iterating through an array. So, when the array is a three dimensional array, each element of that array is 2 dimensional.

Comment: @NomadMaker exactly now it make sense, it took some time to understand it but it make sense.

Comment: @ggorlen got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read that construct as the `for-each` loop. In this case, for each `int[][]` in the `int[][][]`. Another example, `for-each` `int` in an `int[]`.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3};
for (int i : arr) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```